# Socket.io handling disconnection on client

Tags: reactjs, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

On my server I am storing rooms and users as they are created or as users join. Problem is on disconnection I remove the user from the room on server using socket.id and remove room if no one is left in it. But on refresh of the page on the client side my server deletes the user/room but user is still in the room on the client.

```
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    for (const [roomName, userIds] of rooms) {
      const userIdIndex = userIds.indexOf(socket.id);
      if (userIdIndex !== -1) {
        userIds.splice(userIdIndex, 1);

        // later add emit message to other users about disconnected user

        if (userIds.length === 0) rooms.delete(roomName);
        return;
      }
    }
  });
```

I would like for user to be reconected after page refresh or if not possible to be redirected to room selection page. I don't need full solutions just point into the right direction.

I tried to emit message from the server on backed when user is disconnected but that doesn't work which makes sense because he is no logner conected. I wanted to emit for example "disconnected" to just that socket and then on frontend I could update currentRoom state and redirect him back. But that didn't work.

Also on here I found someone talking about listening to on("disconnect") on the client but that doesn't work in case of page refresh.

*UPDATE*

Ok I got it to work but it's not perfect in any means. I will leave this open if someone has better solution.

```
socket.on("user-joined", (currentRoom) => {
    //returning user to the room on page reload
    if (rooms.has(currentRoom) && !rooms.get(currentRoom).includes(socket.id)) {
      socket.join(currentRoom);
      rooms.get(currentRoom).push(socket.id);
    }
    if (!rooms.has(currentRoom)) io.to(socket.id).emit("room-doesnt-exist");

    io.sockets.in(currentRoom).emit("request-canvas-state");
  });
```

So basicly I already had this "user-join" where I requested the canvas state from other users in the room when i enter the whiteboard page. I modified it so that after page reload I check if room exists or if this user is already added in the room(after user joins and gets added to the rooms on server this is triggered so this is to prevent duplicate users in my rooms map).

The only problem with this is that if user is the only one in the room and refreshes the page, room gets deleted. I could recreate the room but in my setup I don't store canvas state so it will be blank canvas anyways so I just use "room-doesnt-exist" and on client I redirect the user to room selection and show appropriate message.

Comment: try to handle the socket closing itself: `socket.conn.on("close", (reason) => {` on relay on the event `disconnect` only